# Browser only applies backdrop-filter when Vue <transition /> is over

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a very simple Vue app, when you click the button, a modal will show up.

Typically, a modal has an only half-transparent black background, but I would like to add some `backdrop-filter: blur(4px);`.

You can notice that when the Vue `<transition />` component is ended, then the browser adds the `backdrop-filter: blur(4px);`, which is very weird, because I think it should be realtime.

How can I make `backdrop-filter: blur(4px);` when using `<transition />` component?

---

Please see this minimum example, here is the full code and demo video:

Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OJYlxATOh8&feature=youtu.be

[image: Edit backdrop-filter question]

full code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <button @click="click">Open Modal</button>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div v-if="open" class="modal">
        <div class="backdrop"/>
        <button @click="close">Close</button>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      open: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.open = true;
    },
    close() {
      this.open = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?coffee);
  background-size: cover;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  > button {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  > .backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is what you are looking for:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <button @click="click">Open Modal</button>
    <transition name="modal-fade">
      <div class="modal-outer" v-if="open">
        <div class="backdrop"/>
        <div class="modal">
          <button @click="close">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      open: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.open = true;
    },
    close() {
      this.open = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?coffee);
  background-size: cover;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  > button {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
.modal-outer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
}
.modal-fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-fade-enter-active {
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation: blur-in 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.modal-fade-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal-fade-leave-active {
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation: blur-out 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes blur-in {
  from {
    backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
  }
  to {
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  }
}
@keyframes blur-out {
  from {
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  }
  to {
    backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
  }
}
</style>
```

---

[image: Edit backdrop-filter question]

Comment: Could you explain why this works?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Basically, you need to animate the opacity and blur at the same time. The final state of the animation is for the backdrop to be blurred. That is just how the Vue transition works. You can read more about it in the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html.
Nevertheless, if you pointed exactly to the part that makes you confused, then possibly I could clarify it better.

Comment: The specific part that confuses me is, from my understanding, it seems that the transition is being applied to modal-outer, but you also have a blur on the backdrop, which doesn't seem to get animated.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The transition applies to `modal-outer`, that is the blur animation that you can see during the transition. The `backdrop` is blurred at all times (but you can see it once the transition on `modal-outer` is complete). To be honest you could just move the `backdrop-filter: blur(4px);` to the `.modal-outer` and you would see the same effect.